# Recover code from older commits of a particular branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-commit, recover

I have a branch A. In that branch I have done several commits for eg.
Commit 5
Commit 4
Commit 3
Commit 2
Commit 1
Where commit 1 is the oldest one. All the commits were pushed successfully and i can even see them in bit bucket. The changes i pushed on commit 3 and commit 4 I can't see those changes in my commit 5. How do i recover that data?

Comment: What do you mean by *seeing the changes of commit 3 and 4 in the commit 5*? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm guessing, since you are being pretty vague. You changed something in 3 and 4, committed it. Then you changed something in 5, maybe you un-did what you created in 3 and 4? It really matters how you end up here, try to elaborate on that. Generally speaking, you'll see only edits of _a_ commit when inspecting _that_ commit, you'll never see what was done in the past.

Comment: My colleague did some changes in commit 3 and 4 and pushed it on git. Then I did a git pull did some changes and pushed it for commit 5. Now the commit 5 doesn't have changes done in 3 and 4. When I click on commit 3 and 4 on bitbucket I'm able to see my colleague's changes but when I click on commit 5, my colleague's changes are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your 'commit 5' is not what you intended. You have two possible options.
One:
Use

```
git revert <commit5-id>
```

which will create a new commit undoing  your 'commit 5'. This is the recommended way forward.

Two:
If you have full permissions on the server, and everyone working on the project understands the consequences and agrees,

```
git push -f <remote> <commit4-id>:<branch-name>
```

which will remove 'commit 5' all together.